# No SD card Adapter other options to load operating system

Tags: sd-card, ethernet, operating-systems

I am a little late in the game but I am building my first RPi 2 B machine.

**Background:** I do not have access to a SD card adapter so I am not able to insert my micro SD into my laptop to download/mount an operating system.

**Question:** *Is it possible to load an operating system via another computer and an ethernet connected Raspberry Pi with a micro SD card inserted into it?*

I can get an adapter tomorrow but really wanted to get started tonight.

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will just wait until I have the correct hardware tomorrow. Thanks for your answer. If you want to post it I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but I'll put it out as an idea for anyone in this bind. I was in a similar situation, had one coming from Amazon but it hadn't arrived. Had a 32GB one in my Droid phone with nothing but backed up media on it so I blanked it and put the OS on it via USB. It worked. New micro SD came in today, put it in my phone. Everything is happy.